# Create Pie chart for each Json object

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have one Json with multiple array and foreach array I want to create Pie chart, but I don't know how to do it.

This is the [array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9exQ.png) thet I have. And this is what I tried :

```
function Pie() {

    $.getJSON("/Admin/Attivita/OreOggi", function (data) {

        console.log(data);

        var oreTecico = [];
        var oreTecico = [];
        var oreMalatia = [];
        var oreStraordinario = [];
        var oreInfortunio = [];
        var oreFerie = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            nomeTecnico.push(data[i].nome);
            oreTecico.push(data[i].odinario);
            oreMalatia.push(data[i].malatia);
            oreStraordinario.push(data[i].straordinario);
            oreInfortunio.push(data[i].infortunio);
            oreFerie.push(data[i].ferie);
        };
        // Build the chart
        Highcharts.chart('zdravko', {
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Ore segnate oggi'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y:.1f} h.'
            },
            accessibility: {
                point: {
                    valueSuffix: '%'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: nomeTecnico[0],
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [{
                    name: '',
                    y:0,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                }, {
                        name: 'Odinario',
                        y: oreTecico[0]
                }, {
                        name: 'Malatia',
                        y: oreMalatia[0]
                }, {
                        name: 'Straordinario',
                        y: oreStraordinario[0]
                }, {
                        name: 'Infortunio',
                        y: oreInfortunio[0]
                }, {
                        name: 'Ferie',
                        y: oreFerie[0]
                }]
            }]
        });
    });
}
```

It shows only the last "data". I want to make fo each array one pie. If i have 100 arrays I want 100 pies.

---

UPDATE:

I added this :

```
 data.forEach(function (el) {
            var chartData = [el.data1, el.data2];
           
            var chartContainer = document.createElement('div');
            document.getElementById('zdravko').append(chartContainer);

            Highcharts.chart(chartContainer, {
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: chartData
                }]
            });
           
        });
```

The `chartData` is [array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msl6p.png) of undefined objects.

Is it possible to make `for` or `foreach` inside Highcharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Highcharts.chart` method in a loop, for example:

```
    var data = [{
        data1: 12,
        data2: 25
    }, {
        data1: 67,
        data2: 11
    }];

    data.forEach(function(el) {
        var chartData = [el.data1, el.data2];
        var chartContainer = document.createElement('div');
        document.getElementById('container').append(chartContainer);

        Highcharts.chart(chartContainer, {
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                data: chartData
            }]
        });
    });
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x95pbw7j/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.chart

Comment: `chartData` is undefined. It creates the Pie, but is empty https://i.stack.imgur.com/msl6p.png

Comment: Hi @micev, What do you exactly mean? The above example works correctly.

Comment: In your case Yes it works, passing static data. I have one dinamic  array that I get it from DB, and inside it can be 100 object.

Comment: I provided you only an example how you can create multiple charts in a loop. With your data it should look similar to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sLch5vwp/

Comment: How can I put it in one line/row?

Comment: You can use `display: inline-block` CSS style and set some width, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cz3xs2yv/